# Removing footnotes from pdf bookmarks

Tags: footnotes, bookmarks

I have

```
   \section{My Title\footnote{ My Footnote 1}\footnote{My Footnote 2}}
```

. 
Both pdfLatex and Latex automatically creates bookmarks from my section headers. That's what I want. But they also include the footnotes. So an example of bookmark is

```
   "My Title My foootnote 1 My Footnote 2"
```

. But I want only

```
   "My Title"
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily use the optional argument of `\section` for a different title text in the TOC and in bookmarks:

```
\section[My Title]{My Title\footnote{ My Footnote 1}\footnote{My Footnote 2}}
```

Comment: the problem here is a general one for \footnote in a moving argument; see [the uk faq](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=ftnsect) for solutions

Answer (score 8):

Assuming your using [`hyperref`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) you can disable the `\footnote` command for all pdf-strings by adding the following to your preabmle:

```
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
  \def\footnote#1{}%
}
```

Complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}

% \footnote is a fragile command so can cause troubles in moving
% arguments like in \section. Let's make it robust:
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\robustify{\footnote}

% load hyperref and disable the \footnote command in bookmarks:
\usepackage{hyperref}
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
  \def\footnote#1{}%
}
\begin{document}

\section{My Title\footnote{ My Footnote 1}\footnote{My Footnote 2}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The footnote should also be avoided in table of contentes and headers.

Comment: @LeoLiu Well, that's rather obvious, isn't it? But there are always people who still want to use them there and TeX.sx is *full* with questions regarding footnotes is floats, captions, ... BTW: did you downvote this answer? If yes: care to tell why so I'd be able to improve it?

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is to use the macro `\texorpdfstring` from the package `hyperref`.

This macro switch the text used in the bookmarks of the PDF file.

```
\texorpdfstring{text that will appear in the document}{text used in the bookmark}
```