# How to replace "unsupported tokens in pdf strings" from the argument of a macro?

Tags: hyperref, pdftex

I'm trying to write a class where the arguments of the `\title{}` and `\author{}` commands, used for the title page, automatically call `\hypersetup{}` to set the title and the author in the PDF metadata.

So far I use this piece of code (the `\apptocmd` command is from `etoolbox`)

```
\apptocmd{\title}{
  \hypersetup{
    pdftitle={#1}
  }
}{}{}
```

It works well, but often it happens that the user wants to insert a newline in the title to tune its appearance:

```
\title{My very long long \\ title}
```

While everything still works, I get a warning about the newline being an unsupported token for pdf strings. The user is then forced to do:

```
\title{My very long long \texorpdfstring{\\}{} title}
```

to have the warning silenced.

So the question is: can I automatically remove (or better, replace) tokens that are not allowed in PDF strings according to `hyperref`, and to pass the filtered string to `\hypersetup` to avoid the warning?

If a generic solution is not possible or too difficult, I'd want at the very least to just remove newlines or to replace them with spaces (I've tried to simply redefine the `\\` command in a group before calling `\hypersetup` but I still get the warning).

Comment: Have a look at `hyperref`'s `\pdfstringdefDisableCommands` (see for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/101117/5049)

Comment: That seems exactly what I'm looking for. It'd be great to be an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done with `hyperref`'s `\pdfstringdefDisableCommands`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref,xpatch}

\xapptocmd{\title}{%
  \hypersetup{ pdftitle={#1} }%
}{}{}

\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
  \def\\{}%
}

\title{My very long long \\ title}
\author{Me}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

The example does not remove the extra space in the pdftitle, though…

Comment: It seems that LaTeX still takes care of the extra spaces.

Comment: @Klaidonis you could input it surrounded by no spaces `\title{My very long long\\title}` and disable it with `\def\\{ }`

Comment: That's exactly what I do, but even with additional spaces, the output is a single space nevertheless. Perhaps, by converting it to a "literal string," the result would be different.

Comment: @Klaidonis Why would you want more than one space after another?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I do not want the additional spaces, but if, in this case, the title was defined with one or more spaces around `\\`, then we still get the single space. I was trying to add this as a remark to your last line in the answer.

Comment: @Klaidonis I don't understand what you mean. My answer gives this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/btY13.png which clearly shows _two spaces_ between `long` and `title` (as I mention in may answer). This https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGWAx.png shows no extra space which uses the code from my comment response to you